# Recursive substitution of formulas in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have derived a formula that I want to recursively subsitute later. 
As an example:

```
f = Function("f")
expr=f(x,y).diff(x) + f(x,y).diff(x).diff(x)
expr.subs(f(x,y).diff(x),f(x,y+1))
```

This gives me

```
f(x, y + 1) + Derivative(f(x, y + 1), x)
```

But what I want is

```
f(x,y+1) + f(x,y+2)
```

How do I do this in a nice way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice way is to make the property you want, `f(x, y).diff(x) == f(x, y + 1)`, be a part of function declaration.

```
class f(Function):
  def fdiff(self, argindex):
    if argindex == 1:
      return f(self.args[0], self.args[1] + 1)
    else:
      raise ArgumentIndexError(self, argindex)
```

Now `f(x,y).diff(x) + f(x,y).diff(x).diff(x)` returns `f(x, y + 1) + f(x, y + 2)` directly, without any substitution. By the way, note that `f(x,y).diff(x, 2)` is shorter notation for multiple derivatives.

Explanation: the method `fdiff` implements first derivative of a function, and it has to handle the derivatives in all variables. You didn't say how the derivative with respect to 2nd variable should work, so I have to default on that by raising ArgumentIndexError which will be handled higher up in SymPy.

For example, `f(x,y).diff(x, 3) + f(x,y).diff(x, y)` is now

```
f(x, y + 3) + Subs(Derivative(f(x, _xi_2), _xi_2), (_xi_2,), (y + 1,))
```

where the Subs with unevaluated Derivative is produced because `fdiff` didn't implement that partial derivative.

Comment: Why do you have argindex == 1? I thought python starts indexing from 0

Comment: I also find it inconsistent, but that's how argindex of SymPy functions is implemented: it begins with 1.